# Generate the other half of a normal distribution as well using the acceptance-rejection method

Tags: r, statistics, random

The following R code give me only half of a normal distribution; what should I change to the code in order to get the other half?

```
halfnormal <- function(n){
    vector <- rep(0,n)
    for(i in 1:n){
        uni_random <- runif(2) 
        y <- -log(uni_random)
        while(y[2] < (y[1]-1)^2/2){
            uni_random <- runif(2)
            y <- -log(uni_random)
        }
        vector[i] <- y[1]
    }
    vector
}

output <- halfnormal(1000)
hist(output)
```

Comment: Why don't you use rnorm function?

Comment: try `hist(rnorm(1000))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you insist on using that code to generate a standard normal (not recommended, as `rnorm` will be much faster and more accurate), just dot product that entire vector by an equal-length vector consisting of random `(-1, +1)` values.

By the way, the half-normal is also known as the [Chi distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) (with 1 degree of freedom).

Comment: I used dot product but got only a number. My code is "vector%*%runif(n, min=-1, max=1)". How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't want to generate from a uniform distribution, you want to generate random bits. Use `rbinom` with n=1 and p=0.5, or do `runif() < 0.5`. Then replace all occurences of `0` with `-1`.

Comment: sample(c(1,-1),size=n,replace=TRUE) should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

This looks bit like Ziggurat algorithm with Marsaglia's modification, but it's bit different? If you don't want to use any guaranteed-to-work random number generators in R, perhaps this works:

```
   halfnormal <- function(n){
        vector <- rep(0,n)
        for(i in 1:n){
            uni_random <- runif(2) 
            y <- -log(uni_random)
            while(y[2] < (y[1]-1)^2/2){
                uni_random <- runif(2)
                y <- -log(uni_random)
            }
            vector[i] <- sample(c(-1,1),size=1)*y[1] #randomly select the tail
        }
        vector
    }

    output <- halfnormal(1000)
    hist(output)
```